# Devise: init user password without using Devise#password in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sinatra, factory-bot

I am using FactoryGirl for the fixtures of my test environment, and Devise for the authentication. Until now we have been relying on the password= method that Devise provides us to initialize the user fixtures. This allows us to easily set a password on the user.

Now, I need to initialize the password without recurring to the password= function.

I am sharing the same models on two application, being the second a Sinatra App which will have 0 authentication (but authorization). The user will be there, and I want to access it and test with it, without relying on Devise logic (that is a dependency from the first app, the Rails App). So far so good.

Thing is, the model specs must also run in the second app. And without initializing passwords properly, I might run into a stumbling block in the near future. Nevermind the fact that I will probably never need the password in the second app, but the specs that need a user must run (and a user must have a password). Is it possible to define a valid password for the test user without relying on Devise logic (and password=)?

And I would like not to fill up the encrypted_password field with some random string, that's what I'm doing already in the 2nd app factory, but I want to have only one factory definition across both applications, and the unencrypted password must therefore be 'qwerty' human-readable and valid in the Rails App context.